# How to draw rounded line ends using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

Say I am plotting a complex value like this:

```
a=-0.49+1j*1.14
plt.polar([0,angle(x)],[0,abs(x)],linewidth=5)
```

Giving

[image]

Is there a setting I can use to get rounded line ends, like the red line in the following example (drawn in paint)?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The line proprty `solid_capstyle` ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_solid_capstyle)).  There is also a `dash_capstyle` which controls the line ends on every dash.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = y = np.arange(5)

fig, ax = plt. subplots()

ln, = ax.plot(x, y, lw=10, solid_capstyle='round')
ln2, = ax.plot(x, 4-y, lw=10)
ln2.set_solid_capstyle('round')
ax.margins(.2)
```

[image]

This will work equally will with `plt.polar`, which is a convenience method for creating a polar axes and calling `plot` on it, and the the `Line2D` object returned by it.

Comment: To the OP, note that this will also work as a kwarg to `plt.polar`, as it just creates a polar axes and passes things on to `ax.plot`.  For example: `plt.polar(x, y, linewidth=5, solid_capstyle='round')`.

Comment: @JoeKington Fair enough, edited answer to include that comment.